# How to execute shell script from LaTeX?

Tags: shell, latex

I'm trying to do the following in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\execute{/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to execute `/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh` at the moment of `.tex` document processing and inject its output into LaTeX stream. Is it possible at all?

PS. It's **possible** through the package I've made: [`iexec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/iexec)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671079/how-can-i-save-shell-output-to-a-variable-in-latex

Comment: Funny how this is closed as `off topic'.

Comment: Maybe you could move your possible solution with your iexec package into a new answer with a short example? This might give it more visibility than hiding it in a post scriptum not everybody reads.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the question is "closed," I can't post any new answers to it :(

Comment: @yegor256 Yes, I noticed that when I tried to close a new question as duplicate of this :( I already voted to reopen, but no result yet :(

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would do something like the following (partially motivated by what Roman suggested): make your LaTeX file be

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{scriptoutput.tex}
\end{document}
```

and generate the file `scriptoutput.tex` using

```
/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh > scriptoutput.tex
```

You could encode this in a makefile if you want to have it run automatically when necessary. Alternatively, you could use the TeX [`\write18` command](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/what-does-write18-mean/),

```
\documentclass{article}
\immediate\write18{/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh > scriptoutput.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{scriptoutput.tex}
\end{document}
```

and I think that would automatically run the shell script each time you compile the document. The `\immediate` is necessary to ensure that the script is run when LaTeX encounters the command, rather than waiting until a page of output is written. (See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151449/all-about-shipout) for more on the shipout routine.)

Comment: Your solution is certainly more clean than mine. Mine is handy if you have a lot of substitutions though.

Comment: @DavidZ You might want to use `\immediate\write18` instead of bare `\write18`. Without `\immediate` the write operation might be buffered until the next time the shipout routine is called.

Answer (score 45):

As David pointed out, you can use `\write18` to call external programs, then `\input` the resultant output file. However you will probably want to use `\immediate\write18` to make sure the script is executed before calling the `\input`.

Alternatively, if you use newer versions of pdf(la)tex (after 1.40, I think), you can pipe the output directly into the document, by using a piped input command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{|"/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh"}
\end{document}
```

For either method you will need to enable external program calls. For TeXlive distributions, you need to call latex with the `-shell-escape` option, or for MikTeX, I believe the option is `-enable-write18`.

Comment: If you use TeXworks on Windows, you might want to pass `--tex-option=--shell-escape` instead of just `--shell-escape`. Otherwise, you will get a cryptic error message: Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

Comment: The `\input` pipe even works with a shell pipe. E.g., `\input{|"jq -r .my_key my_file.json | wc"}` works!

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in TeX. This [paper (PDF)](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/texhack.pdf) shows you how to write and execute a virus within TeX. The same principles apply for executing a shell script. However in my opinion it is more practicable to write a Makefile, which runs before your LaTeX run and inserts the result.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 11.10 GNU/Linux

```
pdflatex --enable-pipes --shell-escape mytexfile
```

with

```
%...
[This section currently is 
\input{|"wc kmb-box.tex| tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 4"}
% 2000 characters are allowed here

\input{kmb-box}

%...
```

works nicely. ie, this uses wordcount (wc) to report how many characters are in the file kmb-box.tex, which is part of (included in) the document.

(btw If you wanted words rather than characters, just change the number in "-f 4")

Comment: I get errors when I switch the command to "ls". Is there a problem with newlines in the output of the command?

Answer (score 3):

Unless it is imperative that the script is run *while* LaTeX is running I would recommend just using `make` to run LaTeX and you script.

I have used that approach to add word counting for articles and including statistics on bibliographic references.

Let your script generate a `.tex` file and include that in you LaTeX source file.

Below is a snippet from one of my Makefiles:

```
TEX =   /usr/texbin/pdflatex
PREVIEW = /usr/bin/open

REPORT  =   SimMon
REPORT_MASTER = $(REPORT).tex

TEX_OPTIONS = -halt-on-error

SimMon:  $(REPORT_MASTER) countRefferedPages
    $(TEX) $(TEX_OPTIONS) $(REPORT_MASTER)
    @$(PREVIEW) $(REPORT).pdf

countRefferedPages: BibTeXPageCount
    cat *.tex | support/BPC/build/Debug/BPC Castle.bib > litteraturTotal.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it with my own [`iexec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/iexec) package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iexec}
\begin{document}
\iexec{/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh}
\end{document}
```

When the output is not required, I can do just this:

```tex
\iexec[quiet]{/usr/local/bin/my-shell-script.sh}
```