# Add output of a shell command to LaTeX

Tags: shell, latex

This is more of an idle curiosity than a life-or-death problem, but I was curious if it was possible to set my .tex file to automatically run a shell command (in this case, 'grep -FIrn *.py') and show the output in the resulting pdf. I think it's motivating to have my design document have a subsection in the "Future Work" section that shows all of the TODOs I have remaining.

Edit: samcarter suggested a similar question, which is helpful to me, but doesn't completely solve the problem.

I can insert a script into my pdf by doing

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\verbatiminput{scriptoutput.txt}
```

but

```
\immediate\write18{grep -FIrn TODO *.py > scriptoutput.tex}
```

just creates an empty file, despite working fine on the command line. I even turned on `--shell-escape` in my pdflatex settings and that line still doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex#comment120758103_3252957 -- too bad the question is not yet reopend

Comment: maybe https://www.ctan.org/pkg/iexec or the PythonTEX package could be what you are looking for

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Yeah, I'm looking at that question now. It doesn't seem like quite the same, but it might be enough for me to come up with my own answer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Tried your answer and edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
....
\verbatiminput{|"wsl grep -FIrn TODO *.py"}
```

You also need to have `--shell-escape` in your settings, but it works.

Comment: I'll be marking this as the accepted answer in a day or two unless someone else has a better one they'd like to share.